# Why Config.xml of Mage/Checkout module not defining helpers?

Tags: checkout, configuration, helper

I've noticed that in Mage/Checkout module's config.xml,there is not tag defining its helpers but it has three helper classes.

Please let me understand the scenario?

Answer (score 7):

I think its not necessary to define helper class in `config.xml`[As per i know]

As per your question

When you call

```
Mage::helper('checkout')
```

> It will first call

```
public static function helper($name)
    {
        $registryKey = '_helper/' . $name;
        if (!self::registry($registryKey)) {
            $helperClass = self::getConfig()->getHelperClassName($name);
            self::register($registryKey, new $helperClass);
        }
        return self::registry($registryKey);
    }
```

> then it will call

```
 public static function getConfig()
{
    return self::$_config;
}
```

> then

```
 public function getHelperClassName($helperName)
{
    if (strpos($helperName, '/') === false) {
        $helperName .= '/data';
    }
    return $this->getGroupedClassName('helper', $helperName);
}
```

> then

```
 public function getGroupedClassName($groupType, $classId, $groupRootNode=null)
{
    if (empty($groupRootNode)) {
        $groupRootNode = 'global/'.$groupType.'s';
    }

    $classArr = explode('/', trim($classId));
    $group = $classArr[0];
    $class = !empty($classArr[1]) ? $classArr[1] : null;

    if (isset($this->_classNameCache[$groupRootNode][$group][$class])) {
        return $this->_classNameCache[$groupRootNode][$group][$class];
    }

    $config = $this->_xml->global->{$groupType.'s'}->{$group};
```

> // here we get all config.xml object [We don't have helper define so we
>   have only Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element object][If we have defined helper in config.xml then we got helper class name ]

```
    // First - check maybe the entity class was rewritten
    $className = null;
    if (isset($config->rewrite->$class)) {
        $className = (string)$config->rewrite->$class;
    } else {
        /**
         * Backwards compatibility for pre-MMDB extensions.
         * In MMDB release resource nodes <..._mysql4> were renamed to <..._resource>. So <deprecatedNode> is left
         * to keep name of previously used nodes, that still may be used by non-updated extensions.
         */
        if (isset($config->deprecatedNode)) {
            $deprecatedNode = $config->deprecatedNode;
            $configOld = $this->_xml->global->{$groupType.'s'}->$deprecatedNode;
            if (isset($configOld->rewrite->$class)) {
                $className = (string) $configOld->rewrite->$class;
            }
        }
    }

    // Second - if entity is not rewritten then use class prefix to form class name
    if (empty($className)) { 
        if (!empty($config)) {
            $className = $config->getClassName(); 
        }
        if (empty($className)) {
            $className = 'mage_'.$group.'_'.$groupType;
```

> [ we get mage_checkout_helper ] {{group is checkout and groupType is
>   helper}}

```
        }
        if (!empty($class)) {
            $className .= '_'.$class;
```

> [ we get mage_checkout_helper_data]

```
        }
        $className = uc_words($className);
```

> [[ finaly we got Mage_Checkout_Helper_Data]]

```
    }

    $this->_classNameCache[$groupRootNode][$group][$class] = $className;
    return $className;
}
```

---

> EDIT

i think helper tag add in `config.xml` because there are lots of helper class in helper [Not only `data.php`(By default is `data.php`)],,to call different helper class we have to define helper name in `config.xml` so we can call different helper.

I hope you clear now

Comment: I know that without defining in xml, we can access it, but is there any reason to have helpers tag in config.xml?This is what i would like to know.

Comment: check my edit @Manik

Comment: I saw your updated answer, Mage/Checkout/Helper directory has Cart.php,Data.php and Url.php , so this module  has different helper class (as you said), then why this module not defining its helper in its config.xml.

Comment: Did you look at my previous comment?